# Python / Selenium / Beautiful Soup not scraping desired elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm struggling to get this code to extract the desired information from one single page.

I've tried all the usual selenium tactics and added a time delay. Hopefully, it's something simple.  I'm not getting any error messages.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36"
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
capabilities = { 'chromeOptions':  { 'useAutomationExtension': False},'args': ['--disable-extensions']}
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',desired_capabilities = capabilities,options=options)

url='https://groceries.asda.com/product/celery-spring-onions/asda-growers-selection-trimmed-spring-onions/41676'

browser.get(url)
sleep(3)
source_data = browser.page_source
bs_data = bs(source_data,"html.parser")

#product id
try:
    product_id = bs_data.findfindAll('span', {'class': 'pdp-main-details__product-code'})       
    product_id = product_id.replace('Product code:','').strip()
except:
    product_id = "n/a"

#image address 
try:
    for image in bs_data.find("div", {"class":"s7staticimage"}):
        image_url = image.find('img')['src']
except:
       image_url = "n/a"   

#product description
try:
    product_desc = bs_data.find('class',{'pdp-main-pdp-main-details__title'})
    product_desc = product_desc.get_text().strip()
except:
    product_desc = "n/a"

#product price
try:
    product_price = bs_data.find('class',{'co-product__price pdp-main-details__price'})
    product_price = product_price.get_text().strip()
except:
    product_price = "n/a"

print (url,'|',image_url,'|',product_id,'|',product_desc,'|',product_price)        


browser.quit()
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the content is dynamically generated, your `soup` has nothing in it to find. `Selenium` is good enough. I don't know why you have treated the elements as list because there is only one of each on this page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
capabilities = { 'chromeOptions':  { 'useAutomationExtension': False},'args': ['--disable-extensions']}
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/bin/chromedriver.exe',desired_capabilities = capabilities,options=options)
url='https://groceries.asda.com/product/celery-spring-onions/asda-growers-selection-trimmed-spring-onions/41676'

browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(15)
product_id = browser.find_element_by_class_name('pdp-main-details__product-code')
print(product_id.text)
image = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"s7viewer_flyout\"]/div[1]/img[1]")
image_url = image.get_attribute('src')
print(image_url)
```

Output:-

```
Product code: 410212
https://ui.assets-asda.com/dm/asdagroceries/5050854288142_T1?defaultImage=asdagroceries/noImage&resMode=sharp2&id=PqaST3&fmt=jpg&fit=constrain,1&wid=188&hei=188
```